# Simple way to export manually set rectangular area from inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Sure enough, you can open the Export PNG Image dialog, select custom and type the coordinates manually. But that's crazy.

You can also use the Page export, but that means you'll need to re-adjust the page if you're exporting different images from the same .svg file. Also, again, adjusting page to include proper margin and alignment is extra work.

What I usually do is that I create transparent rectangle and I include it in the selection when exporting, then I select Export->Selection.

Those invisible rectangles are easy to lose. Is there another way of exporting set rectangular area (eg. 64x64) without using any helper rectangles or the page size?

Comment: What are you planning to use this for? There may be alternatives (e.g. some extensions), but if they are useful to you depends on your scenario.

Comment: @Moini I have a document that has several icons and logos that share a common theme, which is why I keep them in the same document. However, I want to export them individually, with fixed aspect ratio, margins and alignment. That's what I use the invisible rectangles for, to set up the margin and alignment if the exported png image for each icon/logo.

Comment: I see.

There is a 'slicer' extension you could use: Extensions > Export > Guillotine. Then there are a couple of extensions for exporting icons or other objects: this one supports adding margins: https://gitlab.com/su-v/inx-exportobjects/tree/master ; this one can export multiple sizes: https://github.com/ChristianBecker/inkscape-android-export (there exist a couple of versions of it on github, just search for it). And then you can do batch exports from the PNG export dialog, but they don't add a margin.